# Touches lost altogether (no touchesBegan or touchesEnded)

Tags: ios, iphone, touch, gesture, multi-touch

I'm working on a 60fps racing game on iOS. The game is controlled by 2 thumbs, left and right. Right is used for steering (sliding the finger with touchesMoved) and left is a hold and release for boost (hold for about a second then release).

Once in a while, I get the bug where the left touch doesn't register at all... I don't get touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchEnded or TouchesCancelled when I touch, move or release the left finger. However, if I release the right finger  (the steering finger) when the left hand touch is still there and the bug is happinging (no left finger events called), I get touchCancelled for the right finger touch ... very weird!

95% of the time, everything goes normal, and both left/right generate the events on time as expected. The bug happens only about 5% of the time, and very randomly.

Here is the scenario of the bug in detailed steps:

1- Right finger is already touching (on the right-bottom corner) and it's steering the game with TouchesMoved.

2- Left finger touches the left-bottom corner but no TouchesBegan called when the touch happens.

3- Right finger moving still registers TouchesMoved calls properly as expected.

4- Left finger moving doesn't register anything as if it doesn't exist.

5A- Removing the left finger first doesn't register TouchesEnded or TouchesCancelled. Removing right finger afterwards registers TouchesEnded normally as expected.

or

5B- Removing the right finger first causes TouchesCancelled to be called. Afterwards, removing left finger does nothing as if there was no touch there.

I have one fullscreen UIView that uses OpenGL. Multi-touch is enabled for both the view and the window, and no Gestures are registered (unless if there are some default ones?)

I'm testing on iOs 7.1.1 on iPhone5.

I also noticed that CPU load doesn't make a difference, sometime I get the bug when CPU load is high sometimes when it's low, also no memory warning or memory overloading.

Hopefully someone with deep iOS experience can resolve this mystery.

Comment: Unfortunately no, but it seems to be related to a behavior on long devices (5,5s,6,6+, and iPodtouch 5th) that causes touches near the edge of the screen to be ignored, because the device thinks it's the palm of the holding hand touching the edge of the screen unintentionally.